# Pam configuration for openssh RPM CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, openssh, pam

Our products use CentOS 6.5 and we would like to deploy them with custom openssh RPMs.  I have downloaded the sources from http://athena.caslab.queensu.ca/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable and built the RPMs, but the PAM configuration file is wrong after installation.

When I install the default openssh-5.3p1 RPMs from the CentOS 6.5 repository, the configuration looks like this:

```
> cat /etc/pam.d/sshd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required    pam_sepermit.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the
user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

However, when I rebuild this exact RPM from the source and install it, I get the following:

```
> cat /etc/pam.d/sshd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
password   required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
session    required     pam_stack.so service=system-auth
```

I was wondering if there are any build logs that would show how the openssh RPMs were built from the source for CentOS 6.5.  Perhaps there is some type of configuration I am missing that would ensure that I get the same PAM configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the source RPM (SRPM) for all CentOS released software from most mirrors (and definitely from http://vault.centos.org).

The source rpm contains the entire sources, patches, etc. and the spec file from which the official RPMs are built and will contain the information you are looking for.